# Windows 7 Explorer search won't work

Tags: windows-7, search

I can't make Windows 7 Search work. I type part of the file name, in this case "add" but nothing pops up.

The folder looks like this:
[image]

After the search there are no results:
[image]

Sorry for polish language, hope you can figure.

What I already did:

- Rebuilt the whole index and made sure that the files folder is under indexing
- Turned off and on Windows Search function
- Restarted the laptop several times

I have more than 40k files under indexed locations and only 8k indexed elements as the windows states. I'm not sure, maybe those are folder, not files named as elements here.

Nothing helps and I wish I had a mac. Since I'm stuck with Windows for now, please advice.

Comment: Have you checked your search options to see if something is turned off? Have you tried searching for ```ic_add```?

Comment: I did try ic_add with the same (no) results. If there is something turned off, I can't find it and that might be the reason I'm asking.

Comment: I have added a couple of links having similiar problem in searching for files.  Please let us know status.
 
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/in-windows-7-i-want-to-search-for-all-files/aadfe1f1-4a33-406b-8e72-bb920efa4f30
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/windows-7-search-does-not-work-for-documents/9f82fb0b-eb28-4c07-9130-b0b3944818dd

Comment: @JacekKwiecień: "I wish I had a mac" - You'd rather switch OSes than search utilities? Anyway Win7 search [works](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nfSGr.png) so looks like you've broken something. Perhaps a utility like [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com) will be more to your liking.

Answer (score 2):

This free Microsoft tool may be of some help.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/mats/windows_search

I know the issues with Windows Search are not uncommon. If this will not help, google it with bit more details, there are tips available, just like this:

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-repair-broken-windows-search-windows-7-easily

Comment: LOL. This tool only removed search bar from Windows Explorer. Microsoft is like a dentist. Can't fix the teeth, let's remove it. Ridicolous.

Comment: @JacekKwiecień you can re-add it by going into add/remove Windows features and ticking "Windows Search".

Comment: @JacekKwiecień - Really? Then yes, this is ridiculous. I've never really used windows search much (I'm TotalCommander user since time immemorial)... Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

At some point I got fed up with the standard Windows Explorer search and installed FileLocator Lite.  I can't recommend it highly enough.  https://www.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorlite

Answer (score 0):

Windows Explorer search use Windows Search service. Turn on it.

Change indexing option if need add place:

[image]

Type at Run dialog (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>):

```
search-ms:query=((ext:.doc)OR(ext:.docx)) Underground
```

Comment: What do I do with this?

Comment: search `Underground` word at all .doc and ..docx at all place

Comment: I did say that I turned off and on Windows Search and also made sure folder is under indexing

Comment: You can even search for a disabled search. Simply, it will be much slower and with a lot of CPU time. In your example, you are looking for a part of the file name. You can shorten the search by using the `search-ms:query=LIKE(filename:"*add*")` In this case, the search will not take place within the file and turn on Windows Search. Or use other means of searching and indexing.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make sure search settings are reset is to reinstall Windows. You might also have luck with a System Restore. But my first solution is the only definite answer. And if your leg hurts, and you call the doctor and just say "ow my leg hurts", they'll have to ask a bunch of questions and still might not get to the bottom of the issue, so it is not really a specific question, which is a demand on this website, but rather you have a practical problem, which is not particular in any immediately obvious way.

It might not be obvious, but there are a lot of things that could have affected search indexing, and no one can say better than you what (could have) happened. You haven't even mentioned specifics such as where the folder is located, whether search works in other folders (then there's the debugging part where you compare this folder with others such as path length and whether the path contains diacritics). So now you see how yours is not a question?